# How to simplify this code and make it much easier?

Tags: python, simplify

Hey all programmers there I have a quite funny and mostly easy question. I am working with the esp32 and there I am working with 2 Multiplex 7-segment displays. I have created my code it is working too but I want to have let us say a more beautiful way to code these lines. I have splited my number into 2 numbers (ex. 34 --> [3,4]) and then I am looking with this if-elif and append the line (for outputs on GPIOs) which is correct so 3 would be 0000110. Do you have any Ideas to make this code much easier?

```
             if number == 0:
                 dcd_input_list.append([0,0,0,0,0,0,1])
             elif number == 1:
                 dcd_input_list.append([1,0,0,1,1,1,1])
             elif number == 2:
                 dcd_input_list.append([0,0,1,0,0,1,0])
             elif number == 3:
                 dcd_input_list.append([0,0,0,0,1,1,0])
             elif number == 4:
                 dcd_input_list.append([1,0,0,1,1,0,0])
             elif number == 5:
                 dcd_input_list.append([0,1,0,0,1,0,0])
             elif number == 6:
                 dcd_input_list.append([0,1,0,0,0,0,0])
             elif number == 7:
                 dcd_input_list.append([0,0,0,1,1,1,1])
             elif number == 8:
                 dcd_input_list.append([0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
             elif number == 9:
                 dcd_input_list.append([0,0,0,0,1,0,0])
```

Thank you very much for your help! If I have to send further information just ask.

Ps: It is a Python-Code but that should be clear.

Best regards

Comment: Is that number to binary conversion? Because if it is that way the conversion is awfully wrong.

Comment: Make a list of your 7-segment display lists, so you can use `number` as the index to that list.

Comment: @Sagitario No it isn't a binary conversion this directly. So we are working with open_drains and for this we need the inversion of all bits of course. But I got many solutions now which are very good for me and my application.

Comment: @ScottHunter Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could compress this into a dict:

```
lookup = {
    0: [0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    1: ...and so on
}
dcd_input_list.append(lookup[number])
```

...or a list:

```
lookup = [
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,1,1,1,1],  # ...and so on
]
dcd_input_list.append(lookup[number])
```

Comment: A list would work just as well as a `dict`.

Comment: yup, added that.

Answer (score 0):

You could put all possible values in a list and simply select the relevant index with `number`:

```py
values = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,1][1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1,0],[1,0,0,1,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0]]
dcd_input_list.append(values[number])
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can simplify this is by putting all of these lists into another list, and then append using a one liner that uses the value of `number` as an index for the list of lists. It would look like this:

```
nums_lists = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,1,1,1,1],
    [0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
    [1,0,0,1,1,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,0,0]
    ]
dcd_input_list.append(nums_lists[number])
```